# Animate SVG circle around the circumference of another SVG circle, using RAF

Tags: javascript, svg, requestanimationframe

I am currently trying to learn how to animate with requestAnimationFrame but I am having some issues figuring out how to animate from point-to-point on the circumference of an SVG circle. I am able to find the appropriate points around the target, but when I execute my function it animates directly to the very last point, when the desired effect would be to iterate through the entire list of points and animate to each point sequentially.

```
window.onload = function(){
    var little = document.getElementById("little");
    var big = document.getElementById("group");
    var count = 33;
    var cx = 100;
    var cy = 100;
    var r = 66;
    var px;
    var py;

    function animator(){
        for(var i=0; i<count; i++){
            px = cx + r * Math.cos(2*Math.PI*i/count);
            py = cy + r * Math.sin(2*Math.PI*i/count);
            little.setAttribute("cx", px);
            little.setAttribute("cy", py);
            requestAnimationFrame(animator);
        }
    }

        requestAnimationFrame(animator);

}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jayboodev737/6yrhu785/3/

I am thinking that the issue is with how I am trying to implement RAF itself, but I am at a bit of a loss in regards to how this should be structured. Thanks!

Comment: ~~gee~~ Every time you call `requestAnimationFrame(callback)`, `callback` is stacked in a list of to be called functions that should occur at the next screen refresh. Here you are adding a new callback at every iteration of your for loop: if `count` is 2, at second frame, `animator` will be called twice, at third frame 4 times and like so exponentially blowing your CPU and memory consumption. Please move it after your loop.

Comment: In the same vein, you are changing a single element's attribute in this for loop, that doesn't make sense, setting it only once to the last value would have the same effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be looping through all your values inside your `animator()` function.  The animator function should perform one step itself. Then it calls `requestAnimationFrame()` to schedule the next iteration later.

```js
//window.onload = function() {
    var little = document.getElementById("little");
    var big = document.getElementById("group");
    var count = 33;
    var cx = 100;
    var cy = 100;
    var r = 66;
    var i = 0;

    function animator(){
      if (i === count)
        return;

      var px = cx + r * Math.cos(2*Math.PI*i/count);
      var py = cy + r * Math.sin(2*Math.PI*i/count);
      little.setAttribute("cx", px);
      little.setAttribute("cy", py);
      i += 1;
      requestAnimationFrame(animator);
    } 

    requestAnimationFrame(animator);
//}
```

```css
svg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 600 600" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="clipper">
            <text x="50" y="50" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" font-size="12">FireStarter</text>
        </clipPath>
        <pattern id="patty" x="0" y="0" width=".25" height=".25">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="800" height="800" style="fill:#7047C2;"></rect>
            <g id="group">
                <circle id="little" cx="166" cy="100" r="11" style="fill:#57FA00;" fill-opacity="0.7"></circle>
                <circle id="big" cx="100" cy="100" r="66" style="fill:#2A0033;" fill-opacity="0.3"></circle>
            </g>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="800" height="800" style="fill:url(#patty); transform:translate(-50%, -25%);"></rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: Perfect sir! Thanks for the feedback